# Unable to get Location Enabled YES in Urban Airship

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

I need to get Location services up to send push to the device based on the location . I am using segments to set the location and the time but what I can see in my logs is :

`[UALocationService reportCurrentLocation] [Line 358] Location service not authorized or not enabled.`

I do have `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` keys in my application’s info.plist.

I am not able to find the issue causing the location not enabled. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Code :

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    [UALocationService locationServicesEnabled];
    [UALocationService locationServiceAuthorized];
    [UALocationService airshipLocationServiceEnabled];
    UALocationService *locationService = [UAirship shared].locationService;
    [locationService reportCurrentLocation];
    [locationService startReportingSignificantLocationChanges];
```

Comment: can you place your code for the Location manager ?

Comment: @cyberlobe I have added code. Please check .

Comment: make sure in UALocationService.m iOS 8 Location validation is added like this: requestWhenInUseAuthorization
Also if its old file than Update it with New file.

Comment: @cyberlobe I cannot find UALocationService.m in my project . There's UALocationService.h.

Comment: have you used this ? : https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/blob/master/Airship/Common/UALocationService.m

Comment: No ,I have embedded Airship kit in my project .

Comment: Well i don't have much idea about Airship kit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Searching , I found that we do not need to add CLLocationManager on our own .

> Instead make use of function
>   `coreLocationWillPromptUserForPermissionToRun`  like this:

```
[UALocationService coreLocationWillPromptUserForPermissionToRun];
```

Following are the functions that  we need to invoke to enable services:

```
   [UALocationService airshipLocationServiceEnabled];
   [UALocationService setAirshipLocationServiceEnabled:YES];
   [UALocationService locationServicesEnabled];
   [UALocationService locationServiceAuthorized];
   [UALocationService coreLocationWillPromptUserForPermissionToRun];
```